# Editable Address Book Python

Tags: python, addressbook

I need help making an editable address book python. I need to take be able to allow the user to 1) Enter a new person 2) Edit a person 3) Search for a person and show their information 4) List all names to screen 5) Exit the program. For information, you will want the user to be able to enter the following:

1) First Name
2) Last Name
3) Address
4) City
5) State
6) Zip
7) Phone number

The only required fields are 1 and 2.  Other fields can be left blank by the user.

here is my code so far

```
fName = ""
lName = ""
address = ""
city = ""
state = "" 
zipcode = "" 
phone = ""




def Mainmenu(addressbook) :
return(addressbook)

print ("Main Menu")
print ("1 - enter a new person")
print ("2 - edit a person")
print ("3 - search for a person")
print ("4 - list all names")
print ("5 - exit")
input ("enter your selection")



print ("Welcome to my Address Book program")
choice = int ("Mainmenu"())
print("You chose" , choice)
```

I am very new to programming, like 5 weeks in, and I need help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From my very limited knowledge, it sounds like a class would be fairly helpful.

Comment: There are arguably too many questions in this post for it to be suitable on SO, but for starters you might want to look at a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store your data,

Comment: This looks like you are asking us to do your homework. Try it youserlf and come here with the errors and we will help debugging it. Dictionaries are the way to go for storing key->value pairs. A `list` would contain all the address book,m where its element is a `dict` with the fields you mentioned.

Comment: You can take a look at this post. It combines class objects with dictionaries which would allow you to store multiple fields.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368498/python-object-as-dictionary-value>

Comment: Thanks so much. As I said I am new and just needed pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Address book program with more functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467481/address-book-program-with-more-functionality)

Comment: def Mainmenu():
    print ("Main Menu")
    print ("1 - enter a new person")
    print ("2 - search a person")
    print ("3 -  edit a person")
    print ("4 - list all names")
    print ("5 - exit")
    selection= input ("enter a selection: ")
    return selection

name= Mainmenu()

userdata= ['firstname ', 'lastname ', 'streetaddress ', 'city ', 'state ', 'zipcode ', 'phone']


print (userdata[0] + userdata[1] + userdata[2] + userdata[3] + userdata[4] + userdata[5], userdata[6],"have all been entered")

Comment: So I have gotten a bit farther in terms of assigning some variables, and setting up an array. I am still confused as to how to assign my selection to a specific task